# How to know that which is process allocate memory to?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system

I want to know the zone that process allocate memory to.
I know that I can use

```
cat /proc/pid/status
```

And also

```
cat /proc/zoneinfo
```

Both of this command that doesn't answer where the memory of process allocated to. Is there any other command? And if there is how can I implement it in the kernel?

Comment: You can do it with Valgrind if used properly.

Comment: @Silveris. As far as I know it is using for memory leak detection right?. I read their document. There is no command to check where memory is allocated in which zone.

Comment: If you mean the physical address range, well that is different for every page frame

Comment: So basically i need to find virtual memory address and translate to physical address right?. How can I know that which page frame that this process is mapped to. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @asiandudeCom See the [valgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)'s allocation tree part.