# How would i find if a process is using DMA or DMA_32 space in linux?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have created a syscall which asks the process id from the user. I can find the details of the pages for the process. But i cant find a way to show how much space used by that process in each zone (eg DMA, DMA_32) ?

I could not find any resources regarding this matter too. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you would like to know?  Is it some sort of diagnostic utility, or are you trying to debug something?

Comment: I was studying about memory management and would like to know about the allocation of memory by a process. So i installed a kernel and i am creating a syscall to monitor the process. @Neil

Comment: Are you in the same class as [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674673/how-to-know-that-which-is-process-allocate-memory-to)?